# Styling icons inside a script?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Below is my html, but my interest is in the script. I would like to style the font awesome icons i.e. increase font-size, align etc. Can you add a css element inside the script? I have deliberately isolated the script that I'm speaking about so you don't have to look through the entire code. Its the middle section of the code below

```html
<head>
       <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        
<script>

$(function() {
     $("#toggle-button").click(function() {
            var i = $(this).find('i');
            if ($("#collapse").is(':visible')) {
                i.removeClass('fa-angle-double-up').addClass('fa-angle-double-down');
                $("#collapse").slideUp(400);
            } else {
                i.removeClass('fa-angle-double-down').addClass('fa-angle-double-up');
                $("#collapse").slideDown(400);
            }
     });
});

</script>

</head>
<h2 style="font-family: times-new-roman; font-size: 33px; text-align: center; color:rgb(85,174,249)">BIOGRAPHY</h2>
<div id="collapse" class="biography-box" style="display:none">
    <p>Albert Einstein (14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist.[5] Einstein developed the theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics).[4][6]:274 Einstein's work is also known for its influence on the philosophy of science.[7][8] Einstein is best known by the general public for his mass–energy equivalence formula E = mc2 (which has been dubbed "the world's most famous equation").
    </p>
</div>
<button id="toggle-button" class="btn btn-info" style="color: black; background-color: transparent; border: none; font-color: black; width:778px" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: if you want to edit css properties, why don´t you do that in a css file and let the javascript toggle a class to make selector match it?

Comment: What, exactly are you trying to do? It appears that you already know about `.addClass()`?

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can use jquery.css function for this:

```
$("#toggle-button").click(function() {
    var i = $(this).find('i');
    if ($("#collapse").is(':visible')) {
        i.removeClass('fa-angle-double-up').addClass('fa-angle-double-down').css('color', 'red');
        $("#collapse").slideUp(400);
    } else {
        i.removeClass('fa-angle-double-down').addClass('fa-angle-double-up');
        $("#collapse").slideDown(400);
    }
});
```

.css({'color': 'red','font-size': '33px'}) // for multiple properties

DOCS: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are Using only one fa ICON and I understand you want to style and decorate it by script on page load so that if appears **distinct** and ***catchy***.so here is my solution

```
      $(function() {
              $(document).find(".fa").css('color', 'red').addClass('fa-2x');
              // rest of the code as it is

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use style to use fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, fa-5x to increase font size of the font awesome icon and also for giving another style you can add a different class while you are adding fa-angle-double-down and fa-angle-double-up

```html
   <head>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
          $(function() {
    $("#toggle-button").click(function() {
        var i = $(this).find('i');
        if ($("#collapse").is(':visible')) {
            i.removeClass('fa-angle-double-up').addClass('fa-angle-double-down');
            $("#collapse").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            i.removeClass('fa-angle-double-down').addClass('fa-angle-double-up');
            $("#collapse").slideDown(400);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
    <h2 style="font-family: times-new-roman; font-size: 33px; text-align: center; color:rgb(85,174,249)">BIOGRAPHY</h2>
    <div id="collapse" class="biography-box" style="display:none">
       <p>Albert Einstein (14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born theoretical physicist.[5] Einstein developed the theory of relativity, one of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum mechanics).[4][6]:274 Einstein's work is also known for its influence on the philosophy of science.[7][8] Einstein is best known by the general public for his mass–energy equivalence formula E = mc2 (which has been dubbed "the world's most famous equation").
       </p>
    </div>
    <button id="toggle-button" class="btn btn-info" style="color: black;background-color: transparent;border: none;font-color: black;width: 100%;text-align: right;" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
```